# working on port 81(wampserver)

Tags: wampserver

I have recently installed wampserver 2.0 and configured it to work on port 81. Now the problem is that when I click on phpMyAdmin present at the taskbar inside wampserver 2.0 the browser redirects me to

`localhost/phpmyadmin` instead of `localhost:81/phpmyadmin`. When I manually type it, everything works fine.

How can I fix this thing? I want the browser to open `localhost:81/phpmyadmin` page instead of `localhost/phpmyadmin` when I click on `phpMyAdmin`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The configuration is stored in `wampmanager.ini`, located in the wamp installation directory.

This file is generated from `wampmanager.tpl` though, so you need to change the following line there:

```
Type: item; Caption: "${w_phpmyadmin}"; Action: run; FileName: "${c_navigator}"; Parameters: "http://localhost/phpmyadmin/"; Glyph: 5
```

You can even add your own menu items in there if you like.

You need to restart Wamp after changing this configuration, since `wampmanager.ini` needs to be re-generated.

Comment: Yes, but will it allow a relative link like I suggested?

Comment: @Paul Tomblin: There is no need for a relative link in that case. This is the link to open the start-page of `phpMyAdmin` and it is displayed in a non-html menu (http://www.wampserver.com/en/data/image_menu_wamp.gif) which is configured via the described `ini` file.

Comment: If you make it a relative link, you won't have to change it when you decide to move to port 82 or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, the problem is that your link to phpMyAdmin points to the wrong direction. Now I've never used this server, but the wampserver's taskbar is probably some HTML file. Just look for something like `<a href="http://localhost/phpMyAdmin/">` and replace the HREF with your path there.

Comment: Not in that case (see my answer)

Answer (score 0):

Wherever possible, you should use relative links in your website.  I don't know anything about this "wampserver", but the link to phpmyadmin, instead of being <a href="http://localhost/phpmyadmin">, should be <a href="/phpmyadmin">, and that way it will continue to work no matter what port or domain you're running on.

Comment: Not in that case (see my answer)

Answer (score 0):

Added **:8080** to all 3 `http://localhost` uses in wampmanager.tpl. Saved changes. Exited wampserver. Started Wampserver. Came up green. Clicked localhost inside wampserver menu. Wampserver page opened in browser.

Thank you Peter Lang for your post. It led me to solution I've struggled with for several days.